# Real time notifications on IRC about Stackoverflow questions on a particular topic

Tags: feature-request, support, irc

Is there a way to put a Real time notification system in place, which notifies an IRC channel as soon as questions are posted with specific tags on Stackoverflow?

I have seen something similar with Github - There are IRC channels that show notifications when github issues are created to projects of interest.

Answer (score 2):

Such an app already exists: [StackIRC - Posting Questions from Stack Exchange Sites to IRC Channels](https://stackapps.com/questions/3695/stackirc-posting-questions-from-stack-exchange-sites-to-irc-channels)

**Disclaimer:** I wrote the app.

Comment: +1 This looks interesting. Just curious about the fact weather it makes repeated requests to fetch data for particular tags "long poling" or does it make use of the asynchronous RSS notifications from the Stack.PY API?

Comment: It uses Stack.PY to repeatedly poll the Stack Exchange API.

Answer (score 1):

SE provides RSS feeds, so yes.  (I.e. the feed for the "discussion" tag is: `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/discussion`.)

If someone were suitably motivated they could create a program that would subscribe to those RSS feeds and then interact with an IRC channel based on the information provided.